# Keeping laptop battery healthy

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, dell-latitude, battery-life

On our old Lenovo's, we used to have a Lenovo app which would stop the battery from charging when it reached 100%, it would then let the charge drop to 90%, and then it would charge the battery back up to 100% before repeating that process again.

According to the Lenovo app, this helps keep the battery healthier for longer.

We now have Dells, and do not have such an app installed by default.  I checked the Dell website, does Windows 10 Enterprise have a built in way of achieving the same goal?

Comment: All laptops have this behavior built-in. Even your Lenovo laptop, though it defaults to a 96% threshold.

Comment: Charging to 100% and cycling to 90% is NOT good for the battery. You want to charge to no more then 80%, while keeping it at between say 60 and 65% is ALOT closer to the ideal - which is why batteries are shipped charged at about 60-70%. My Dell devices allow you to set charging profiles in its BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

A lithium-based battery can not be overcharged even if you leave it plugged in at all times because as soon as it is fully charged (100%), the internal circuit prevents further charging until there is a drop in the voltage.

As soon as the charge level reaches 100% the battery stops receiving charging energy and this energy is bypassed directly to the power supply system of the laptop.